# Passing a reference to an object contained within a 'packet' object over a socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, object, reference, serializable

I know that it is impossible to pass a reference to an object on another machine or in a separate process, but could an object be passed as a reference if the object being referenced is also sent over a socket? Or would the only way to accomplish the same thing is to pass both as objects and then re-attatch their references upon receiving the 'packet'  object?

As I am writing this, another idea just occurred to me, does the Java Serializable class copy the contents of references when the references are serialized?

Comment: A "reference" is a memory address.  You don't know what the memory address will be on the remote system, so I'd say officially "no".  However, you can send a complete copy of an object, and reconstruct a replica over on the remote side.  Some call this serialization, some call this "marshaling", but in essence you would have 2 exacting replicas.  But, those replicas are just that...replicas.  Changing on will not effect a change in the other, unless you are syncronizing your objects somehow manually.

Comment: That's what I think I'll have to do. The problem is I have two object arrays that contain references to specific objects in the array of the other type. So I guess I'll have to re-create the references. Repost as an answer? This is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: So, you have two objects, each with an array/collection inside, and they reference each other?  Like a ManyToMany or something?  Have you considered just sending the whole blob at once?  Maybe wrap all the objects you need to send in some message wrapper, that way they are all wired together when they pop out the other end?

Comment: Yeah, I do. I send the original object containing the references over the socket. They they pop out as objects not references on the other side. I need to re-create the references when the entire thing is received.

Comment: How are you sending your objects?  If you send them one at a time, you are going to have problems.  Your better off sending them as a bunch, already wired together.  If you are sending two or more objects that reference each other, you could create some sort of "message" wrapper object to put them all in together and send them at once.  Also, you may want to look at other methods to serialize other than the native Java serialization framework.  We used to use XFire in my old job to write objects out because it was XML and didn't have issues with object versioning.

Comment: I did that. Literally all of the objects are in two arrays that are contained inside of my 'packet' object which is sent as one big lump at once. XML serialization guarantees destruction of references, because the contents of each object are expanded, not given a reference number. Look at the XML output.

Comment: Right, I see the problem: circular references.  I think XStream is supposed to handle those types of references, but you would need to use it on both sides: serialization and de-serialization.  Which library are you using right now to serialize to XML?

Comment: The Java built-in xml serialization. I have solved the problem by reconstructing the references when the object is deserialized. This is the same thing any xml serializer would do.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a reference to an object as it is just a number.  The receiving end just sees a number.

You can copy the contents of an object and the address where it came from but the address is still useless to you.

Java Serialization does a deep serialization, copying all the objects it refers to.

Comment: @rob any reference to an object which is not Serializable prevents the whole data structure being serialized (and corrupts the stream)

Comment: In Java there is no way of getting the actual reference number. Either way that is not helpful to me. I was essentially asking if there was a way to preserve Java references if the object being referenced is sent over the socket too. I don't think Java can do this though. Even if I could get the actual reference number, it would be useless on another machine. Even on another process, as the object wouldn't exist at that address.